# Show that $[\mathbb{Z}_n : m\mathbb{Z}_n] = \frac{n}{gcd(m,n)}$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer, and let m be any integer. Show that $[\mathbb{Z}_n : m\mathbb{Z}_n] = \frac{n}{\gcd(m,n)}$.

My understanding is that  $[\mathbb{Z}_n : m\mathbb{Z}_n]$ represents the order of the quotient group $\mathbb{Z}_n / m\mathbb{Z}_n$.

For example: $[\mathbb{Z}_6 : 3\mathbb{Z}_6]$ = 3 since $\mathbb{Z}_6 / 3\mathbb{Z}_6$ = {{0,3}, {1,4}, {2,5}}.

But 3 $\neq$ $\frac{6}{\gcd(3,6) = 3} = 2$.

Am I using incorrect definitions, or is the HW question incorrect?

Answer (score 3):

Under the canonical projection $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_n$, the subgroup $ m\mathbb{Z}_n$ is the image of $m\mathbb{Z}$ and its preimage is $m\mathbb{Z}+n\mathbb{Z}=\gcd(m,n)\mathbb{Z}$.

Therefore, $[\mathbb{Z}_n : m\mathbb{Z}_n] = [\mathbb{Z} : \gcd(m,n)\mathbb{Z}]=\gcd(m,n)$.